# Chat / System Communication App (Nodejs + RabbitMQ)

Tags: node.js, sockets, rabbitmq, chat, cluster-computing

So i currently have a chat system running NodeJS that passes messages via rabbit and each connected user has their own unique queue that subscribed and only listening to messages (for only them). The backend can also use this chat pipeline to communicate other system messages like notifications/friend requests and other user event driven information.

Currently the backend would have to loop and publish each message 1 by 1 per user even if the payload of the message is the same for let's say 1000 users. I would like to get away from that and be able to send the same message to multiple different users but not **EVERY** user who's connected.

(example : notifying certain users their friend has come online).

I considered implementing a rabbit queue system where all messages are pooled into the same queue and instead of rabbit sending all user queues node takes these messages and emit's the message to the appropriate user via socket connections (to whoever is online).

[Proposed - infrastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gl9C.jpg)

This way the backend does not need to loop for 100s and 1000s of users and can send a single payload containing all users this message should go to. I do plan to cluster the nodejs servers together.

I was also wondering since ive never done this in a production environment, will i need to track each socketID.

Potential pitfalls i've identified so far:

- slower since 1000s of messages can pile up in a single queue.
- manually storing socket IDs to manually trasmit to users.
- offloading routing to NodeJS instead of RabbitMQ

Has anyone done anything like this before? If so, what are your recommendations. Is it better to scale with user unique queues, or pool all grouped messages for all users into smaller (but larger pools) of queues.

Comment: What's the software you use for infrastructure diagram?

Answer (score 1):

as a general rule, queue-per-user is an anti-pattern. there are some valid uses of this, but i've never seen it be a good idea for a chat app (in spite of all the demos that use this example)

RabbitMQ can be a great tool for facilitating the delivery of messages between systems, [but it shouldn't be used to push messages to users](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/21/how-to-do-user-notifications-from-rabbitmq-messages/).

> I considered implementing a rabbit queue system where all messages are pooled into the same queue and instead of rabbit sending all user queues node takes these messages and emit's the message to the appropriate user via socket connections (to whoever is online).

this is heading down the right direction, but you have to remember that RabbitMQ is not a database (see previous link, again).

you can't randomly seek specific messages that are sitting in the queue and then leave them there. they are first in, first out.

in a chat app, i would have rabbitmq handling the message delivery between your systems, but not involved in delivery to the user.

your thoughts on using web sockets are going to be the direction you want to head for this. either that, or [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource).

if you need persistence of messages (history, search, last-viewed location, etc) then use a database for that. keep a timestamp or other marker of where the user left off, and push messages to them starting at that spot.

you're concerns about tracking sockets for the users are definitely something to think about.

if you have multiple instances of your node server running sockets with different users connected, you'll need a way to know which users are connected to which node server.

this may be a good use case for rabbitmq - but not in a queue-per-user manner. rather, in a binding-per-user. you could have each node server create a queue to receive messages from the exchange where messages are published. the node server would then create a binding between the exchange and queue based on the user id that is logged in to that particular node server

this could lead to an overwhelming number of bindings in rmq, though.

you may need a more intelligent method of tracking which server has which users connected, or just ignore that entirely and broadcast every message to every node server. in that case, each server would publish an event through the websocket based on the who the message should be delivered to.

if you're using a smart enough websocket library, it will only send the message to the people that need it. socket.io did this, i know, and i'm sure other websocket libraries are smart like this, as well.

...

I probably haven't given you a concrete answer to your situation, and I'm sure you have a lot more context to consider. hopefully this will get you down the right path, though.

Comment: thank you for your response, i did do some googling and your blog was one of the first places i visited, however upon further research the volume of users i was using (200k+)  resulted in looking to use architecture that was geared towards queue / channels per-user (facebook). Which seemed ultimately like the better approach programmatically.

On the NodeJS layer i am using Socket.IO so this is good news to hear that it would technically ignore messages that were not intended for a particular user, however i'm using my systems own assigned user id sent with the socket connection.